# C++ implementation of SHA-512 not working

Tags: c++, hash, sha, sha512

I need to implement a couple versions of SHA in C++, mostly from the ground up, for a summer camp. [Here's the docs for the algorithm](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf).

I've gotten SHA-1, SHA-224, and SHA-256 working perfectly, but I haven't managed to get 512 or its derivatives right. I'm supposed to be getting `ddaf35a193617aba cc417349ae204131 12e6fa4e89a97ea2 0a9eeee64b55d39a 2192992a274fc1a8 36ba3c23a3feebbd 454d4423643ce80e 2a9ac94fa54ca49f`, but my program gives me `21fb47208172306 4570d403444f23d 3fcab6a24097aaf4 7920558b5eea0ae8 7cfc6ce26543e3a6 8ba9c07d1b89d02 1e27ad9d5487df13 2e4a745e0e4df60`.

main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <sstream>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::string msg = "abc";
    std::string hashedMsg = hash(msg);
    std::cout << "Hash:" << std::endl << hashedMsg;
    std::cin.get();
}
std::string hash(std::string msg)
{
    //Preprocessing 
    const unsigned char eighty = 0x80;
    unsigned long long msgLength = msg.length() * 8;
    unsigned long long msgBitSize = _byteswap_uint64(msgLength);
    unsigned long long k = 1024 - ((msgLength + 64 + 1) % 1024);
    unsigned long long finalSize = msgLength + 1 + k + 64;
    unsigned long long hashValues[] = {
        0x6a09e667f3bcc908, 0xbb67ae8584caa73b, 0x3c6ef372fe94f82b, 0xa54ff53a5f1d36f1,
        0x510e527fade682d1, 0x9b05688c2b3e6c1f, 0x1f83d9abfb41bd6b, 0x5be0cd19137e2179
    };
    std::vector<unsigned long long> words(finalSize / 64);
    std::memcpy(words.data(), msg.c_str(), msg.length());
    std::memcpy((unsigned char *)words.data() + msg.length(), &eighty, 1);
    std::memcpy((unsigned char *)words.data() + msg.length()+1+((k-7)/8), &msgBitSize, 8);
    unsigned char* byte = (unsigned char*)words.data();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size() * 8; i++) {
        std::bitset<8> b(byte[i]);
        std::cout << b << " " << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (int)byte[i] << std::endl;
    }
    // Processing
    unsigned long long workingValues[8];
    unsigned long long a;
    unsigned long long b;
    unsigned long long c;
    unsigned long long d;
    unsigned long long e;
    unsigned long long f;
    unsigned long long g;
    unsigned long long h;
    unsigned long long temp1;
    unsigned long long temp2;
    for (int chunk = 0; chunk < words.size(); chunk += 16) {
        std::vector<unsigned long long> schedule(80);
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            schedule[i] = _byteswap_uint64(words[chunk + i]);
        }
        for (int i = 16; i < 80; i++) {
            schedule[i] = (s1(schedule[i - 2]) + schedule[i - 7] + s0(schedule[i - 15]) + schedule[i - 16]) % (long long)(pow(2, 64));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            workingValues[i] = hashValues[i];
        }
        a = workingValues[0];
        b = workingValues[1];
        c = workingValues[2];
        d = workingValues[3];
        e = workingValues[4];
        f = workingValues[5];
        g = workingValues[6];
        h = workingValues[7];
        for (int t = 0; t < 80; t++) {
            temp1 = (h + S1(e) + ch(e, f, g) + sha::words[t] + schedule[t]) % (long long)(pow(2, 64));
            temp2 = (S0(a) + maj(a, b, c)) % (long long)(pow(2, 64));
            h = g;
            g = f;
            f = e;
            e = (d + temp1) % (long long)(pow(2, 64));
            d = c;
            c = b;
            b = a;
            a = (temp1 + temp2) % (long long)(pow(2, 64));
        }
        hashValues[0] = (hashValues[0] + a) % (long long)(pow(2, 64));
        hashValues[1] = (hashValues[1] + b) % (long long)(pow(2, 64));
        hashValues[2] = (hashValues[2] + c) % (long long)(pow(2, 64));
        hashValues[3] = (hashValues[3] + d) % (long long)(pow(2, 64));
        hashValues[4] = (hashValues[4] + e) % (long long)(pow(2, 64));
        hashValues[5] = (hashValues[5] + f) % (long long)(pow(2, 64));
        hashValues[6] = (hashValues[6] + g) % (long long)(pow(2, 64));
        hashValues[7] = (hashValues[7] + h) % (long long)(pow(2, 64));
    }
    // Return final message
    std::stringstream ss; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { 
        ss << std::hex << hashValues[i]; 
    } 
    return ss.str();
}
```

main.h:

```
#pragma once
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<bitset>
namespace sha {
    const unsigned long long words[] = {
        0x428a2f98d728ae22, 0x7137449123ef65cd, 0xb5c0fbcfec4d3b2f, 0xe9b5dba58189dbbc,
        0x3956c25bf348b538, 0x59f111f1b605d019, 0x923f82a4af194f9b, 0xab1c5ed5da6d8118,
        0xd807aa98a3030242, 0x12835b0145706fbe, 0x243185be4ee4b28c, 0x550c7dc3d5ffb4e2,
        0x72be5d74f27b896f, 0x80deb1fe3b1696b1, 0x9bdc06a725c71235, 0xc19bf174cf692694,
        0xe49b69c19ef14ad2, 0xefbe4786384f25e3, 0x0fc19dc68b8cd5b5, 0x240ca1cc77ac9c65,
        0x2de92c6f592b0275, 0x4a7484aa6ea6e483, 0x5cb0a9dcbd41fbd4, 0x76f988da831153b5,
        0x983e5152ee66dfab, 0xa831c66d2db43210, 0xb00327c898fb213f, 0xbf597fc7beef0ee4,
        0xc6e00bf33da88fc2, 0xd5a79147930aa725, 0x06ca6351e003826f, 0x142929670a0e6e70,
        0x27b70a8546d22ffc, 0x2e1b21385c26c926, 0x4d2c6dfc5ac42aed, 0x53380d139d95b3df,
        0x650a73548baf63de, 0x766a0abb3c77b2a8, 0x81c2c92e47edaee6, 0x92722c851482353b,
        0xa2bfe8a14cf10364, 0xa81a664bbc423001, 0xc24b8b70d0f89791, 0xc76c51a30654be30,
        0xd192e819d6ef5218, 0xd69906245565a910, 0xf40e35855771202a, 0x106aa07032bbd1b8,
        0x19a4c116b8d2d0c8, 0x1e376c085141ab53, 0x2748774cdf8eeb99, 0x34b0bcb5e19b48a8,
        0x391c0cb3c5c95a63, 0x4ed8aa4ae3418acb, 0x5b9cca4f7763e373, 0x682e6ff3d6b2b8a3,
        0x748f82ee5defb2fc, 0x78a5636f43172f60, 0x84c87814a1f0ab72, 0x8cc702081a6439ec,
        0x90befffa23631e28, 0xa4506cebde82bde9, 0xbef9a3f7b2c67915, 0xc67178f2e372532b,
        0xca273eceea26619c, 0xd186b8c721c0c207, 0xeada7dd6cde0eb1e, 0xf57d4f7fee6ed178,
        0x06f067aa72176fba, 0x0a637dc5a2c898a6, 0x113f9804bef90dae, 0x1b710b35131c471b,
        0x28db77f523047d84, 0x32caab7b40c72493, 0x3c9ebe0a15c9bebc, 0x431d67c49c100d4c,
        0x4cc5d4becb3e42b6, 0x597f299cfc657e2a, 0x5fcb6fab3ad6faec, 0x6c44198c4a475817
    };
}
std::string hash(std::string msg);
unsigned long long rotr(unsigned long long x, unsigned int n) {
    return (x >> n) | (x << (32 - n));
}
unsigned long long ch(unsigned long long e, unsigned long long f, unsigned long long g) {
    return (e & f) ^ ((~e) & g);
}
unsigned long long maj(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, unsigned long long c) {
    return (a & b) ^ (a & c) ^ (b & c);
}
unsigned long long s0(unsigned long long x) {
    return rotr(x, 1) ^ rotr(x, 8) ^ (x >> 7);
}
unsigned long long s1(unsigned long long x) {
    return rotr(x, 19) ^ rotr(x, 61) ^ (x >> 6);
}
unsigned long long S0(unsigned long long x) {
    return rotr(x, 28) ^ rotr(x, 34) ^ rotr(x, 39);
}
unsigned long long S1(unsigned long long x) {
    return rotr(x, 14) ^ rotr(x, 18) ^ rotr(x, 41);
}
```

If it helps, I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I've tried using the built-in 64-bit cl.exe compiler, and while it does give me a different hash, it's still not the target one. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `% (long long)(pow(2, 64));` that's a bug here. I suppose that `unsigned long long int` is 64-bit, so you can remove this part. Instead of `unsigned long long`, use `uint64_t`.

Comment: why is that massive data table in a header file??

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Instructor demanded that the table be in the header; not my fault. Expected output is listed in the post: `ddaf35a193617aba cc417349ae204131 12e6fa4e89a97ea2 0a9eeee64b55d39a 2192992a274fc1a8 36ba3c23a3feebbd 454d4423643ce80e 2a9ac94fa54ca49f`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two bugs in this implementation:

1. In `rotr`, you should have `64 - n` instead of `32 - n`
2. You should remove all `% (long long)(pow(2, 64));`. If you used `uint64_t` instead of `unsigned long long`, these weren't needed. And they cause bug here, because `long long` is usually 64-bit, and it cannot store the number 2^64. Using `uint64_t` "automatically" uses modulo 2^64.

And it is questionable to put all these function definitions and data into the header file. You should use `inline` for function definitions, at least. But you'd better move them into the `.cpp`.

Comment: The data table is in the header file because my instructor wants it there. I'll try this when I get home.